Optimization techniques to solve dynamically changing weighted graphs?
Our professor has given us an exploratory problem at the intersection of Game Theory and Graph Theory and I was feeling a little stuck so I wanted some tips on how to proceed.
The game is set as follows that there are n players, each player has i choices and there is a payoff function V(n,i) that varies based on the player and the choice.
Additionally, the players communicate with each other and both n1 and n2 incur a penalty $$P(n1, n2) \iff i1 \neq i2$$
An example of the game can be



Players
Choice 1
Choice 2
Choice 3




1
7
4
8


2
8
5
4


3
5
3
6



And the penalties are as follows



Player a,b
Penalty




1,2
10


1,3
0


2,3
8



The idea is assuming it to be a transferable utility game, what would be the pareto efficient outcome. The above is just a simplified example of a game, however the optimization algorithm must work for any particular graph or network given and a scalable implementation.
I assumed I can model the situation as a weighted graph, however am unsure on how to proceed. I cannot solve the game in a linear program also since to test for penalties I am having to multiply two decision variables.
Any tips on how to proceed or papers/algorithm I can read would be much appreciated.

From what I see, this can be solved using basic linear programming. Let's first set up the problem.
We have $n$ players, each with $i$ choices. Each choice gives a utility of $V(n,i)$. There is also a penalty $P_{n1,n2}$ which is active when players $n1$ and $n2$ don't have the same choice. Every $P$ has a different value.
The first new variable that I'm going to define is $\mu_{i,j}$ for every player $i$ and choice $j$. It is a binary variable. If equal to 1, then player $i$ has made choice $j$. The other variable that I will be defining is $v_{i,j}$, the utility going to player $i$ from choice $j$. Next, the total utility of a player, that is: $$ u_{i} = \sum_{j=1}^{J} v_{i,j} \mu_{i,j} $$
Of course we have to restrict $\mu_{i,j}$. $$\sum_{j=1}^{J} \mu_{i,j} \le 1 $$
because a player can have only one choice.
The only thing left, I think, is the penalty which we already have defined. The way we check for it in a linear programming code, you'll see in the code I provided below.
The overall objective function is: $$max: \sum_{i=1}^{N}u_{i} - \sum_{i=1,k=1}^{I} P_{i,k} $$
Note: Yes I know that the sum of all penalties that I provided will give unnecessary values like $P_{1,1}$ but these can be ignored.
I made a code in python using pulp to try and solve the simple problem you gave above.
from pulp import LpMaximize, LpProblem, LpVariable, lpSum, LpStatus

model = LpProblem(name="problem", sense=LpMaximize)

utilities = {
    (1, 1): 7, (1, 2): 4, (1, 3): 8,
    (2, 1): 8, (2, 2): 5, (2, 3): 4,
    (3, 1): 5, (3, 2): 3, (3, 3): 6
}

mu = {(i, j): LpVariable(f"mu_{i}_{j}", cat='Binary') for i in range(1, 4) for j in range(1, 4)}
u = {i: LpVariable(f"u_{i}", lowBound=0) for i in range(1, 4)}
p12 = LpVariable("p12", lowBound=0)
p13 = LpVariable("p13", lowBound=0)
p23 = LpVariable("p23", lowBound=0)
for i in range(1, 4):
    model += u[i] == lpSum(utilities[(i, j)]*mu[(i, j)] for j in range(1, 4)), f"Constraint_u_{i}"
for i in range(1, 4):
    model += lpSum(mu[(i, j)] for j in range(1, 4)) <= 1, f"Sum_constraint_{i}"

for j in range(1, 4):
    model += p12 >= 10*(mu[(1, j)] - mu[(2,j)])
    model += p12 >= 10*(mu[(2, j)] - mu[(1, j)])

for j in range(1, 4):
    model += p23 >= 0*(mu[(2, j)] - mu[(3,j)])
    model += p23 >= 0*(mu[(3, j)] - mu[(2, j)])

for j in range(1, 4):
    model += p13 >= 8*(mu[(1, j)] - mu[(3,j)])
    model += p13 >= 8*(mu[(3, j)] - mu[(1, j)])

model += u[1] + u[2] + u[3] - p12 - p13 - p23, "Objective"
model.solve()
print("Status:", LpStatus[model.status])
for var in model.variables():
    print(var.name, "=", var.varValue)

Of course, this has to be generalized for bigger models but you get the idea. If you want to generalize, I suggest you use matrices. As far as I see it, you'll need a matrix for all $v_{i,j}$ values and one for the penalties.
